# Como hacer restricciones como CONSTRAINT en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

No me deja hacer constraints en phpmyAdmin, entonces no puedo agrupar mis propias restricciones y nombrarlas como quiera y tengo que ponerlas justo después del nombre de la columna. El ponerlas separadas sería muy útil para por ejemplo poner un conjunto de columnas como clave candidata.
Ejemplo

'''

```
CREATE TABLE empleado(
    codigo SMALLINT(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    fechaNacimiento DATE,
    salario SMALLINT(7) NOT NULL
);

/*y me gustaría ponerlas así-->*/

CREATE TABLE empleado(
    codigo SMALLINT(5),
    nombre VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    fechaNacimiento DATE,
    salario SMALLINT(7) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cod_pk PRIMARY KEY codigo
    CONSTRAINT dni_nom_ap1_ap2_uk UNIQUE(dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2)
);
```

/*con las restricciones abajo, si alguien me puede indicar si es una limitación o algo sería de mucha utilidad. ¿Y que forma hay de codificar que hay varias claves candidatas en phpmyadmin?, gracias.*/

'''

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo:

```
    CREATE TABLE empleado(
            codigo SMALLINT(5) PRIMARY KEY,
            nombre VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            apellido1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            apellido2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            dni VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            fechaNacimiento DATE,
            salario SMALLINT(7) NOT NULL CHECK (salario>0)
);
```

Comment: Debes indicar si es la respuesta correcta, eso significa que ya has probado tu código y en efecto solventa tu duda. Puedes editar tu respuesta si es así.

Comment: OCHOA no me deja ponerla como correcta hasta dentro de 2 días, gracias de todas formas, no lo sabía.